# Convert javax.servlet.http.Part to Java.io.File

Tags: java, file, jsf, glassfish, converters

Iam working on a webapplication using java 8, maven and a glassfish-server.

Iam trying to convert a Part object to a File object with following Code to use it for the javaMail attachment.

First of all My Application Folder looks Like This[image]

And My Code:

```
public  void copyPartToFile() throws IOException{
    InputStream inputStream = part.getInputStream();
    String contentType = part.getContentType();
    String pathname = "GradePlus/Attachment/tmpFile."+ contentType.substring(contentType.lastIndexOf('/') +1);
    File copy = new File(pathname);
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(copy);
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } finally {
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

The Stacktrace is saying, that there was no such file or directory.

```html
 #{fileBean.copyPartToFile}: java.io.FileNotFoundException:GradePlus/Attachment/tmpFile.csv (No such file or directory)
javax.faces.FacesException: #{fileBean.copyPartToFile}: java.io.FileNotFoundException: GradePlus/Attachment/tmpFile.csv (No such file or directory)
 at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
 at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
 at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
 at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1692)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:654)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:483)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:180)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: GradePlus/Attachment/tmpFile.csv (No such file or directory)
 at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
 at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
 ... 35 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:GradePlus/Attachment/tmpFile.csv (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
 at controller.FileBean.copyPartToFile(FileBean.java:132)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
 at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
 at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
 at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
 at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
 ... 36 more
]]

[2018-03-02T20:08:55.497+0100] [Payara 4.1] [WARNUNG] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1520017735497] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/arbnor/Documents/Repositories/Software_Projekt2/GradePlus/GradePlus/Attachment/tmpFile.csv (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
 at controller.FileBean.copyPartToFile(FileBean.java:132)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
 at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
 at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
 at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
 at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
 at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
 at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
 at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
 at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1692)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:654)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:483)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:180)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace rather than vaguely describe it?

Comment: Rename your file variable to part, to make your code more readable, post the complete stack trace of the exception when asking about an exception, and use an absolute path rather than a relative one, since your container is probably not started from the project directory, and there won't be any such project directory once your app is deployed to production anyway.

Comment: The pathname will be referred from classpath and the location "GradePlus/Attachment/tmpFile" is not in classpath. You may read using fully qualified location - like ~/Documents/GradePlus/Attachment/tmpFile.. or use getResourceAsStream and put the file in the JVM classpath.

Comment: @Midhun that's completely incorrect.

Comment: @JBNizet I´ve also tried to put my absolute Pathname but the same Exception appeared

Comment: I rather put my part as an argument for javaMail attachment, but It seems not possible, atleast from what i´ve read so far..

Comment: Look at your screenshot, and read the stack trace. The folder is named "Attachments" (with a final s), and the path ends with GradePlus/GradePlus/Attachment/tmpFile.csv (double GradlePlus, an no final s in "Attachment").

Comment: Thank you for the hint but the output in the Stacktrace remains the same after adding the s. The File will just not be created in the Directory.

Comment: So you really have a GradlePlus folder inside another GradlePlus folder?

Comment: The file is not created because the directory doesn't exist. Look at the error message.

Comment: @JBNizet The upper Gradeplus Folder is the our whole repository, the second one contains alle the coding stuff.

Comment: @EJP yes,  but the directory definitely exists.

Comment: What's the output of `ls /Users/arbnor/Documents/Repositories/Software_Projekt2/GradePlus/GradePlus/Attachments/`

Comment: there is nothing. the directory is empty.

This one doesnt seem to  save the File

File copy = new File(pathname);

Comment: The File just has to be saved temporary, I just want to attach it to a JavaMail message object and delete it afterwards.

Comment: **Never ever** (try to) store uploaded files in your webapp or in the container

Comment: @sergeantSalty No, it doesn't exist. See the error message. It doesn't lie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a relative path name.  That name is relative to the directory where the GlassFish server was started.  The `GradePlus/Attachment` directory probably doesn't exist there.  It would be much better to use an absolute path name so you know exactly where the file will end up.

Since this is just a temporary file, consider using the [File.createTempFile method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Also, note that you can simplify your code using the [MimeBodyPart.saveFile method](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#saveFile-java.io.File-).

Comment: An absolute path **outside** the container or the webapp!

Comment: Thank you Bill, the suggestion with createTempFile method worked perfectly!